# Не срабатывает слушатель на ObservableList javafx

Tags: javafx

Есть список BooleanProperty:

```
 private final ObservableList<BooleanProperty> booleanList = 
        FXCollections.observableArrayList();
```

Небходимо, чтобы при изменении состояния какого-либо экземпляра BooleanProperty (например,

```
 BooleanProperty flag1 = new SimpleBooleanProperty(false) ... 
 flag1.set(true) и т.д.)
```

с false на true или наоборот срабатывал слушатель.
Пробовал так, не получается:

```
 booleanList.addListener((ListChangeListener
            .Change<? extends BooleanProperty> change) -> {
        System.out.println("!!!");
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Добавьте слушателя на `SimpleBooleanProperty` вот так

```
BooleanProperty flag1 = new SimpleBooleanProperty(false);

flag1.addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
    System.out.println("Новое значение " + newValue);
});

flag1.set(true);
```

Либо меняйте сам список

```
ObservableList<BooleanProperty> booleanList = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
booleanList.addListener((ListChangeListener<BooleanProperty>) c -> System.out.println("Список изменился"));
booleanList.add(flag1);
```